# NativeScript ScrollView when component open it will scroll to some section

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-angular

im using ScrollView  in my component like that

```
        <ScrollView height="108"
                    orientation="horizontal"
                    sdkToggleNavButton>
                         .
                         .
                         .
                     some content
        </ScrollView>
```

with scroll width about 1200, i'm looking for some way that when the component opens it will appears in the middle of that scrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scrollView.scrollToHorizontalOffset(position);`